# Trouble switching from While True code to a function

Tags: python, function, arduino

I have code written in Python and Arduino using serial communication, and I didn't organize it into functions or a class originally, so I am trying to do so now in order to make it more readable and easier to use. However, I am having trouble with switching from an infinite loop to a function that can be called multiple times. The infinite loop works fully, making the motors run and printing out the right statements, and the function enacts the print statements, but it won't make the motors run.

General Python code with infinite loop:

```
while True: 
    ser.write('a'.encode())       #used as an initial byte

    ...other code... mostly assigning values to the variables below

    motorBytes = bytearray([decToByte(left), decToByte(right), decToByte(leftMid), decToByte(rightMid), distPerc])      #puts the motor values into an array as hex
    print(motorBytes)

    ser.write(motorBytes)
```

General Python code with function:

```
def motor_loop(distObject, forceGraspL, forceGraspR, maxForceL, maxForceR):
    ser.write('a'.encode())

    ...other code... mostly assigning values to the variables below

    motorBytes = bytearray([decToByte(left), decToByte(right), decToByte(leftMid), decToByte(rightMid), distPerc])      #puts the motor values into an array as hex
    print(motorBytes)

    ser.write(motorBytes)
    return

motor_loop(1.5, 0, 30, 60, 60)        #call the function
```

The values are sort of arbitrary, for I am printing the values that are being sent through serial communication on both sides, and they are the correct values.

General Arduino Code:

```
void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available()>0)    //checks to see if anything needs to be sent,
  {                            //denoted by recieveing signal from pySerial 
     char inByte = Serial.read();


     if (inByte == 'a') 
     {
       run_loop();
     }   
  }         
}   

 void run_loop()
{
  int num = Serial.readBytes(values, 5);
  if (num < 5)
  {
     return;
  }

  writeMotor(mtrPinLeft, mtrSpeedLeft, mtrPinRight, mtrSpeedRight, mtrPinLeftMid, mtrSpeedLeftMid, mtrPinRightMid, mtrSpeedRightMid);
```

(where writeMotor is a function that will write all of the motor values to the correct pins.)

I have a feeling that the section of code in the arduino bit in run_loop(): with the return, in order to have the function not run if it does not hold all of the data. Can anyone confirm this hunch and have any suggestions on how I might fix this? I am not super familiar with functions either, so I could be missing something with how to deal with functions. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** ser is declared as ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM4') and all of the variables above (left, right, leftMid, etc.) are declared in the space where it says other code

Comment: What does  print(motorBytes) show and what does ser.write(motorBytes) return?  The function may or may not know what "ser", "left", "right", etc. are as they are not passed to the function, but may be global in scope.

Comment: @CurlyJoe all of those are declared, I just left them out so my question text was not even longer! Though I can add them in if you think it is necessary. Also, I thought it might not be necessary, because the text in the while loop and the function are the exact same except for what I've posted, and the while loop does run as expected.

Comment: print(motorBytes) returns bytearray(b'\xff\x00\xaa\x00\x00') and ser.write(motorBytes) returns the same thing in arduino, but without the bytearray part. These are the expected values.

Comment: ser.write() usually returns the number of bytes written, but it depends on the serial package in use.  If you are not getting that then there is a problem with the write, i.e. ser not declared properly, etc.

Comment: @CurlyJoe I see what you mean now about the function not being passed the global variables, sorry I keep misunderstanding what you mean, and I think you are right. Though I'm not sure why it appears that my serial connection is working (I was able to print values that were sent through serial) if that is so.

Comment: Since ser is a global variable, if I add that in as a parameter to my function call, when I do call the function, do I just use ser as the parameter? e.g. motor_loop(1.5, 30, 0, 60, 60, ser)

Comment: Yes.  Use the name passed to the function (i.e. used in the function definition)